# How can I send emails using my own mail server in Meteor?

Tags: email, meteor, smtp

I am trying to enable [email support for my Meteor application](http://docs.meteor.com/#email), and since I have my own server I want to also use my own mail server. So I installed `postfix` in my `Debian wheezy` server and successfully sent and email to my GMail address, so that means the mail server works properly and sends emails.

When I deploy my Meteor app and try to send an email though, say to do a password reset, my app crashes with the following error:

```
Exception while invoking method 'forgotPassword' RecipientError: Can't send mail - all recipients were rejected
at Object.Future.wait (/home/loupax/phial/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:326:15)
at smtpSend (packages/email/email.js:94)
at Object.Email.send (packages/email/email.js:155)
...
...
```

My `MAIL_URL` environment variable is in the format `MAIL_URL=smtp://my_domain.tld`.

Comment: @Flexo: While the fix is a one-liner, it's a useful solution not mentioned in [the Meteor documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#email) (and wasn't a user error like a typo; rather a lack of docs). Can you please reopen the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like all I had to do, is change the `MAIL_URL` environmental variable from `smtp://my_domain.tld` to `smtp://localhost`. After that everything worked just fine

Comment: Note that this works with `postfix`, which is a full-blown email server, but with `msmtp`, this didn't work. When trying to send email, I get `Exception while invoking method 'forgotPassword' Error: connect ECONNREFUSED at smtpSend (packages/email/email.js:94)`

Comment: In my case because I was using Docker. I needed to trust the docker IP range as well in my /etc/postfix/main.cfg file: `mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 172.17.0.0/16 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128`. 172.17.x.x is the range of Docker containers.

Then I could use smtp://serverip to connect to from Docker container to the host machine which runs Postfix.

Answer (score 0):

Is your server on Amazon? Sometimes SMTP servers are known to block anything sent from certain hosting providers entire IP ranges to block spam.

You might want to consider using a different SMTP server, Amazon's [SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/), or [Mandrill](https://atmospherejs.com/package/mandrill) (which has a meteorite package to help) (personally I use both [SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) and [Mandrill](https://atmospherejs.com/package/mandrill)).

Note its not only Amazons IP blocks which are in this, its also any hosting provider a spammer can quickly set up. Your SMTP sever probably employs a list from somewhere with all these ips on it

Comment: The server is a Debian Wheezy VPS where I have root access. Like I said, I can send emails from my server. My wordpress that is served from the same machine can send emails properly for example, so the problem most certainly comes from node/meteor

Comment: @Loupax does your wordpress work with the same SMTP settings or do you go directly to postfix with a plugin or something?

Comment: I'll check again when I have access to the server, but I certainly can send email via the command line as well. `echo "This will go into the body of the mail." | mail -s "Hello world" me@gmail.com` for example works and it sends me an email from my currently logged in account

Comment: @Loupax it sounds like its not the next SMTP server causing the problem but the postfix bit of it, try sending an email via SMTP as you would from Meteor, postfix might need some more configuration, I guess it thinks the emails your sending to are local it needs to be set to send anything outward for delivery

Comment: @Askhat seems like you were right. I tried connecting to the smpt port of my server via telnet, and at the moment I tried to set the `rcpt to:` field, I got a `554 5.7.1 <me@domain.tld>: Relay access denied`

I'll check the mail server configuration some more

Comment: Found the cause of the problem. Trying to connect to the smtp server by its domain name caused it to break. When I changed the `MAIL_URL=smtp://my_domain.tld` to `MAIL_URL=smtp://localhost` my meteor application started sending mails properly

Comment: If you use Gmail, you can also set `MAIL_URL=smtp://smtp-relay.gmail.com:25/` (no need for any password) and whitelist your server's IP in the control panel of your Google Apps domain. Note that it may take a while (1 hour?) for Google to whitelist the IP, during which you'll get `Exception while invoking method 'forgotPassword' SenderError: Mail from command failed - 550 5.7.0 Mail relay denied - gsmtp`.

Answer (score 0):

for forgot password email, follow below steps

1) create smtp.js file in server folder and past below code in it

```
 Meteor.startup(function () {
   process.env.MAIL_URL = 
   'smtps://abcd@gmail.com:password@smtp.gmail.com:465';
 });
```

2) paste below code in forgot password.js file

```
   Template.forgot.events({

'click #forgot'(event,template) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let email = $("#email").val();

    // paste below code in server.main.js -> in Meteor.startup function.

    /* Accounts.urls.resetPassword = function(token) {
        return Meteor.absoluteUrl('reset-password/' + token);
    };*/

    Accounts.forgotPassword({email:email},function (error,result) {

        if(error)
        {
            alert(error);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(result);
            alert("mail sent ..!! Check your mail box");
           FlowRouter.go('/login');
         }
      });
   }

 });
```

3 ) in main.js file in server folder paste below code 
       import '../server/smtp';

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  // code to run on server at startup
    Accounts.urls.resetPassword = function(token) {
        return Meteor.absoluteUrl('reset-password/' + token);
    };
});
```

check your mail